# How to get particular values from text file using python

Tags: python

I am reading address,netmask,gateway and dnsname-server values from given text file and storing them into var1,var2,var3 and var4 respectively.**In my code I am getting variables instead of that their values**.How can I extract that **addresses values** from below given text file.I am new to file editing in python.All help appreciated.I already read such text edit questions and answers but they were not helpful me in my case.

```
def read_values():
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split()
        print('List:',lines)
        for i, l in enumerate(lines):
            if l.startswith('address'):
                var1 = l
                print('address:', var1)
            if l.startswith('netmask'):
                var2 = l
                print('netmask:', var2)
            if l.startswith('gateway'):
                var3 = l
                print('gateway:', var3)
            if l.startswith('dns'):
                var4 = l
                print('dns:', var4)

read_values()
```

This is text.txt file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 125.222.2222
   netmask 455.225.222.22
   gateway 236.256.222.22
   dns-nameserver 123.256.223.22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following dict constructor with list comprehension:

```
dict(l.strip().rsplit(maxsplit=1) for l in open('text.txt') if any(l.strip().startswith(i) for i in ('address', 'netmask', 'gateway', 'dns-nameserver', 'iface eth0 inet')))
```

This will return:

```
{'address': '125.222.2222', 'netmask': '455.225.222.22', 'gateway': '236.256.222.22', 'dns-nameserver': '123.256.223.22'}
```

Comment: thanks Its work for me.And also If I am adding one more line to detect *static* using your solution : **dict(l.split() for l in open('text.txt') if any(l.strip().startswith(i) for i in ('iface eth0 inet','address', 'netmask', 'gateway', 'dns-nameserver')))** i am getting error. @blhsing

Comment: Thanks ,this is a nice single line solution.@blhsing

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer so that it handles `'iface eth0 inet'` as well.

Comment: Here you are opening file  so ,are we have to  explicitly  close that file after it execute this dict line?

Comment: It's generally okay not to close the file after reading it unless you're opening a huge number of files and risk running out of file descriptors, or you somehow need to delete it within the same script in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:                        #Iterate each line
        val = line.strip()                #Strip leading and trailing space. 
        if val.startswith('address'):     #Check for value
            var1 = val
            print('address:', var1)
        if val.startswith('netmask'):
            var2 = val
            print('netmask:', var2)
        if val.startswith('gateway'):
            var3 = val
            print('gateway:', var3)
        if val.startswith('dns'):
            var4 = val
            print('dns:', var4)
```

**Output:**

```
('address:', 'address 125.222.2222')
('netmask:', 'netmask 455.225.222.22')
('gateway:', 'gateway 236.256.222.22')
('dns:', 'dns-nameserver 123.256.223.22')
```

Comment: I dont need whole line i need like this var1=125.222.2222,var2=455.225.222.22 so I can use that values later in my program but thanks for help.@Rakesh

Comment: You can replace that before storing in variable Ex: `var1 = val.replace("address", "")`.

Comment: or use val.split(" ")

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is in the lines such as

```
var1 = l
```

if `l.startswith('address')` then `var1` becomes "address". You want the list element right after that:

```
var1 = lines[i + 1]
```

Similar comment for `var2`, `var3`, and `var4`. So your code would be:

```
def read_values():
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split()
        print('List:',lines)
        for i, l in enumerate(lines):
            if l.startswith('address'):
                var1 = lines[i + 1]  # <===
                print('address:', var1)
            if l.startswith('netmask'):
                var2 = lines[i + 1]  # <===
                print('netmask:', var2)
            if l.startswith('gateway'):
                var3 = lines[i + 1]  # <===
                print('gateway:', var3)
            if l.startswith('dns'):
                var4 = lines[i + 1]  # <===
                print('dns:', var4)

read_values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just replace it within your print statement

for example

```
print('address:', var1.replace("address", "").strip) \\strip to get rid of new whitespace you created with the replace
```

this however would keep the , and the '...if you wanted to lose those your best bet would be a regex either that or 2 more replace statements which may look bad